# Highcharts zones fail to work correctly with yAxis min max values set

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts 5.x.x

I setup zones on a series of data to stop a solid line being drawn at value 0. 
This works fine when the yAxis.min and yAxis.max properties are not defined, however after setting those two properties the zones are ignore and a solid line appears.

Toggle comment the yAxis config.
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mcr6edhg/1/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
yAxis: { min: 0, max: 100 },
xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
series: [
    {
    data: [
      [
        1499249640000,
        0.003
      ],
      [
        1499249700000,
        1.9205
      ],
      [
        1499249760000,
        1.9611
      ],
      [
        1499249820000,
        1.928
      ],
      [
        1499249880000,
        0.943
      ],
      [
        1499249940000,
        0.944
      ],
      [
        1499250000000,
        0.952
      ],
      [
        1499250060000,
        0.044
      ],
      [
        1499250120000,
        0.961
      ]
    ],
    type: 'area'
},{
        zones: [{
      value: 0.01,
      color: 'rgb(255, 255, 255, 0)'
    }],
    data: [
      [
        1499249640000,
        0
      ],
      [
        1499249700000,
        0
      ],
      [
        1499249760000,
        1.9611
      ],
      [
        1499249820000,
        0
      ],
      [
        1499249880000,
        0.943
      ],
      [
        1499249940000,
        0
      ],
      [
        1499250000000,
        0
      ],
      [
        1499250060000,
        0
      ],
      [
        1499250120000,
        0
      ]
    ],
    type: 'line'
}]
```

});

Comment: Could you please post live example of your issue, so we can find the best solution in your case? How would you like your final chart to look?

Comment: Sorry, example added

Comment: It looks like a bug to me.  If you adjust your max down to 3, the line disappears.  Also, if you notice at higher values for max, the line for zeros is thinner than the other lines.

Comment: I have posted this issue on Highcharts GitHub. Related topic: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6928